# Retrieve all records by table name and variable key in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a controller to which I pass the name of the table/model(: object), an attribute (: key) and the search criteria (: id):

```
def getAll
    obj = params.require(:object)
    datarecord = obj.classify.constantize
    key=params[:key] + "= :i";
    render json: { result: datarecord.find(:all, :conditions => [ key, {:i =>params[:id]}])}
end
```

Unfortunately, I don't get the expected result. The error message is 0 records found but 2 records expected.

For example, I pass following parameters to my controller: 
object: "Opportunity"
key: "account_id"
id: 2

As a result, I want to retrieve all records in the opportunities table which belong the account with account_id=2.

Any idea what is wrong in my code?

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution:

```
def getAll
  obj = params.require(:object)
  datarecord = obj.classify.constantize
  render json: { result: datarecord.where(params[:key] => params[:id]) }
end
```

## Recommendation:

```
def get_all
  model = params.require(:model).safe_constantize
  conditions = params[:conditions].to_h
  records = model.where(conditions)
  render json: { result: records }
end
```

- Example request:

  - model = 'Opportunity'
  - conditions = { 'account_id' => 2 }

Answer (score 0):

`.find` will always return 1 record what you want (if I understood correctly) is `datarecord.where(key => params[:id])`

`where` will return all records and you already have the key and the value that the key should be